# JavaScript / Node.JS to convert an object into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that looks like this:

```
[
  {'el': 123},
  {'el': 234}, 
  {'el': 345}
]
```

I would like to convert this  to an array that holds just the values, and remove the extra 'el' inside:

```
var myArray = [ 123, 234, 345];
```

Is there any easy way to do this, without using JSON.parse or other JSON friendly methods? Old fashioned Javascript is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply loop over the array of objects and only `push()` the values into a new one.

```
var arrOfObjs = [
    { 'el' : 123 } ,
    { 'el' : 234 }, 
    { 'el' : 345 }
];

var arrOfVals = [];
for each( var obj in arrOfObjs ) {
    arrOfVals.push( obj.el );
}

for each( var val in arrOfVals ) {
    console.log( val ); // 123, 234, 345
}
```

Comment: Why use a for loop when you have the native map function?

Comment: `var arrOfVals  = arrOfObjs.map(function(it){ return it.el})`

Answer (score 12):

The most elegant way is:

```
let arrayToMap = [
  {'el' : 123},
  {'el' : 234},
  {'el' : 345}
];
let mappedArray = arrayToMap.map(item => item.el);
```

You can also do:

```
let mappedArray = [
  {'el' : 123},
  {'el' : 234},
  {'el' : 345}
].map(item => item.el);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 var rawArray = [
    {'el': 123},
    {'el': 234}, 
    {'el': 345}
 ]

 var myArray  = rawArray.map(item=>item.el);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const _ = require( 'lodash' );
const mappedArray = _.map( arrayToMap, 'el' )
```

Comment: You should add an explanation about what your code does. I guess it's loading a library, but it's name gives no clue about it's functionality.